# SurveyJS and NextJS - Issue when setting new state of variable

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state, surveyjs

**Version of NextJS:** 12.0.8

**Version of SurveyJS:** 1.9.5

**Testing Browser:** Chrome, FF

**Testing the app (vercel):**
You can test the app here: https://jem-surveyjs-nextjs.vercel.app/

**Description of the issue:**
I combine SurveyJS with NextJS to generate a multi-page survey. The code for the survey is added into a component.
A custom variable can be manipulated using useState.
Every time the variable is set to a different value the survey reloads and jumps back to the first page instead of staying on the current page.
You can clearly see this effect in the dev-tools console.

[image]

**To replicate the issue simply do the following:**

- Create a Nextjs app
- Add the survey-react module (npm i survey-react)
- add the following content to **assets/json/survey-json.js**

  ```
  export const surveyJSON = {
      "pages": [
       {
        "name": "page1",
        "elements": [
         {
          "type": "radiogroup",
          "name": "Speech Test",
          "hasComment": true,
          "commentText": "add comment",
          "choices": [
           "item1",
           "item2",
           "item3"
          ]
         }
        ]
       },
       {
          "name": "page2",
          "elements": [
           {
            "type": "radiogroup",
            "name": "Try again",
            "hasComment": true,
            "commentText": "add comment",
            "choices": [
             "item4",
             "item5",
             "item6"
            ]
           }
          ]
         }
      ]
     };
  ```

- Add the following content to **components/Survey.js**

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import * as SurveyJs from "survey-react";
import "survey-react/survey.css";

import {surveyJSON} from "../assets/js/survey-json";


// Survey Component
const Survey = (props) => {

    const [custParam, setCustParam] = useState(false);


    // Avoid rehydration conflict
    // https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
    const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setHasMounted(true);
    }, []);
    if (!hasMounted) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Handle Custom Function
     */
    const handleClick = () => {

        // Example 3:
        setCustParam(!custParam);
        console.log("HANDLE CLICK - CUSTOM PARAM: ", custParam)
    };


    /**
     * afterRenderQuestionHandler
     */
    const afterRenderQuestionHandler = function (survey, options) {

        // Example 2:
        //setCustParam(!custParam);
        console.log("AFTER RENDER QUESTION - CUSTOM PARAM: " , custParam)

        const tarea = document.querySelector('.sv_q_other');
        if ( tarea ) {
        
            tarea.onclick = function(){ 
                handleClick(); 
            }
            
        }

    }

    let mySurvey = new SurveyJs.Model(surveyJSON);
    mySurvey.showCompletedPage = true;

    // Example 1:
    //setCustParam(true);
    console.log("BEFORE RENDER SURVEY - CUSTOM PARAM: " , custParam)

    return (
        <SurveyJs.Survey
            model={mySurvey}
            onAfterRenderQuestion={afterRenderQuestionHandler}
        />
    );
}

export default Survey;
```

- Finally add this to your **pages/index.js**

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import Survey from '../components/Survey'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
            <Survey />
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you can see I have added 3 different examples of how the issue can be created in the components/Survey.js. Example 3 is the active one right now, but you can un-comment Example 2 or Example 1 to see a different effect of the issue.

How can I avoid this reloading and jump to the first page?

Any help that can point me in the right direction would be appreciated

**UPDATE:**
Many thanks @juliomalves!! 
I have added a useState for my Survey Object
`const [mySurvey, setMySurvey]       = useState({});`

and inside the already existing useEffect I've added the following:
`setMySurvey( new SurveyJs.Model(surveyJSON) );`

I finally just had to remove this line to make it all work: 
`let mySurvey = new SurveyJs.Model(surveyJSON);`

Comment: Try moving the survey init code `new SurveyJs.Model(surveyJSON)` inside a `useEffect` with an empty dependencies array. With your current code a new instance of the survey is created whenever you update the `custParam` state variable, hence causing the survey to reset entirely.

Comment: Thanks juliomalves - see update section at bottom of my question